# Ansible - Prompt for User Input only for Specific host in a Group

Tags: ansible

I have a multiple environments adn i classified them in groups and each group have multiple hosts

During execution of playbook i want user to enter the instruction so to do this i came across the **pause module** but problem is this it only runs for 1st host in the group and ignores all other hosts even though i set the when condition. Is there a way that this prompt can only be run for the servers mentioned in when condition.

```
- name: Reading user input to start/stop for aio or manually
        pause:
          prompt: "You want to stop Application from aio or manually "
        register: restartmethod
        when: deploypackages == "y" and (ansible_default_ipv4.address == "192.168.4.28" or ansible_default_ipv4.address == "192.168.5.28" or ansible_default_ipv4.address == "192.168.6.28" or ansible_default_ipv4.address == "192.168.7.28" )
```

Comment: Checking for IP adresses in a `when` condition is a bad approach - that's not how you should handle your inventory. Put your servers into groups instead. AFAIK prompts can only occur in the top most definition of a play.

Comment: Yes, Servers are in group , and you are right Prompt are in only in top level definiation but i read(after googling)  we can use pause module but problem is it only runs on first host of the group

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Reading user input to start/stop for aio or manually
        pause:
          prompt: "You want to stop Application from aio or manually "
        run_once:  true (Remove this)
        register: restartmethod
        when: deploypackages == "y" and (ansible_default_ipv4.address == "192.168.4.28" or ansible_default_ipv4.address == "192.168.5.28" or ansible_default_ipv4.address == "192.168.6.28" or ansible_default_ipv4.address == "192.168.7.28" )
```

Remove the line run_once so it will execute on hosts when  condition meets

Comment: Sorry, run_once was added for testing purposes. Now after removing it simply Skips it , even though the condition is there ansible_default_ipv4.address == "192.168.7.28"